# HTML/CSS navigation menu: side on desktop; fullscreen on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, navigation

I have a website with a fixed side navigation menu (it's new and I'm only doing the design at this point, so excuse the nonsense content).

This works fine on large displays. But, on mobile displays, the side navigation and the content will not fit on the screen at the same time.

The arrangement I would like to have is:

- on large screens, the side navigation bar appears, taking up part of the width of the screen
- on small screens, the side navigation bar is replaced by a single button fixed at the top of the screen, which causes the navigation bar to appear in fullscreen

I have the large screen part working, but I'm unsure how to achieve the small screen part, or even if it is possible at all.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```css
#side-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#main-content {
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#side-menu a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />

<div id="side-menu">
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
  <a href="#">Navigation link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Navigation link 2</a>
  <img src="example.jpeg">
</div>

<div id="main-content">
 <h1>The main content goes here
</div>
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@media` rule for doing that. You can add this piece of code to your CSS file :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #side-menu {
    ...
  }
}
```

`(max-width: 600px)` will just apply the styles you have specified to the elements within it for devices that are 600 pixels wide and below.

I hope my answer will help you